# My employer has written bad reviews on my relieving letter, he is deliberately spreading bad reviews

Tags: professionalism, employer-relations, india, relieving-letter, rights

[image]

My employer is threatening me, he told, he will give negative feedback in bgv, he is trying to defame my image. what action can I take in india

Comment: Consider not posting the screenshot or make it much smaller (also the top of the screenshot has cut off and corrupted text which makes it confusing to look at). Explain your problem in your own words rather than including a huge screenshot of some kind of 'evidence'. This is not a court.

Comment: Add a country tag, although it seems pretty clear that this is India. This type of reference would be illegal in most countries so I suggest talking to a lawyer or posting  in https://law.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Possibly relevant, but not an answer: [Preventing abuse in countries where relieving letters are the norm](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/33925/10905)

Comment: On a side-note, did you really delete [...] complete code of entire sprint at client place? Will the client company back you in saying that this is a lie? Or is the lie that you have mental issues, not that you deleted something out of anger?

Answer (score 3):

If I'm not mistaken, you need the relieving letter to start at any new place of employment.   The fact is, if the above is stated in your relieving letter it would definitely reflect negatively upon you. Even if you were mentally sick, chances are that local laws protect you from people divulging this information.  Your best course of action is to consult a lawyer and discuss you options for "action" with him/her.

Comment: I would think that this "relieving letter" more reflects badly on the previous employer, who I would immediately categorize as a complete nutcase.

Comment: It is run by two people, they are using very bad means to make money from their employees.