# My Ex Employer has been delaying Relieving Letter and Left over Salary

Tags: recruitment, resignation, india, relieving-letter

Well, apparently, it seems this sort of extortion/exploitation is quite common in India. I am experiencing the same on my end for the last 3 months. Multiple WhatsApp messages, multiple confirmations of finalizing the documented procedure, and finally the threatening tone because of asking about delays. There is some leftover salary as well.

All in all, there is no power on the side of the employee in this entire situation. What are my options now? I have sent an email finally few days before but still no reply from them.

I have served a complete notice period as per contract and the excuse I am being given for delays is that I haven't completed my assignment due to which the company suffered revenue loss; this after I completed the project transfer procedure with another developer.

This is mentally draining and I wonder if I can do something against the employer without compromising my future endeavors.

Comment: Unfortunately the Indian working culture is creating a lot of disadvantages for employees against employers. There are many similar questions here. Probably only a lawyer can help you at this point.

Comment: That's true. The problem is that there is no awareness either information about the platforms where people like me can approach.

Comment: The title refers to "My Ex Employee", the question reads like you mean "My Ex Employer".  Perhaps a typo?

Comment: Yes. It's a typo

Comment: Maybe answers to this question will help you? [Preventing abuse in countries where relieving letters are the norm](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/33925/preventing-abuse-in-countries-where-relieving-letters-are-the-norm)

Comment: I see several digital attempts to reach out.  What about a phone call and/or in-person visit (or safest closest thing possible that isn’t an email)

Comment: "the excuse I am being given for delays is that I haven't completed my assignment"  Has the company proposed a solution on how you can rectify this?  If not, have you asked for one?

Comment: Not yet. Just digital messages. Will try going to meet them personally.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is nothing much which you can do at the moment. While I completely empathise with you, there is no action that will guarantee you your reliving letter and pending salary.

A lawyer could help but it is a rather tedious and long process.

In case you decide to stop following up, leave a detailed review of your experience on Google and Glassdoor.